# Emoji displayed on database not displayed correctly

Tags: php, database, emoji

I have emojis stored in my database on my post titles, they are displayed correctly, like this 
The database field is encoded like this : UTF8-Unicode
the Collation says : utf8mb4_unicode_ci

When I display the post_title, I don't see correctly the Emojis like on the database.

With a script I would like to explode the title by doing this, and it's not working
$post_title_tab = explode("", $post_title);

I tried with utf8_decode and utf8_encode, not working...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

Your database charset may be set improperly, in order to store emojis (and other 4 bytes characters in databases such as mysql you need to use the charset utf8mb4).

If you're using mysql run the following query, it will convert your table's charset to the one required for emoji

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

Comment: In fact the Encodage says : UTF-8 Unicode
And the Collation says : utf8mb4_unicode_ci